# JQUERY - Button trigger as many time div element has

Tags: javascript, jquery

Either 1 button clicked, getting 3 trigger actions. Not sure why it calls 3 times instead of getting the value of a clicked button.

if clicked the first button, it has to click only that button and get the title as "Test 1". But, it calls all 3 buttons at the same time.

```js
$('.listing .btn.apply').click(function(){
    let getTestName = $(this).parent().find('h1').text();
    console.log('getTestName: ', getTestName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class"wrapper">
    <div class="listing">
        <h1>Test 1</h1>
        <a href="test1.html" class="btn apply">Apply</a>
    </div>
    <div class="listing">
        <h1>Test 2</h1>
        <a href="test2.html" class="btn apply">Apply</a>
    </div>
    <div class="listing">
        <h1>Test 3</h1>
        <a href="test3.html" class="btn apply">Apply</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code as written only logs once per button clicked. It does not recreate the problem you described.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.listing .btn.apply').click(function(evt){
let getTestName = $(evt.target).parent().find('h1').text();
console.log('getTestName: ', getTestName); });
```

Explanation:
Your code doesn't specify which element will receive the event click, so jquery propagated to all elements with the same selector, you restrict to the "target" element which is clicked

Comment: Why exactly? The code as written performs the same.

Comment: Your code doesn't specify which element will receive the event click, so jquery propagated to all elements with the same selector, you restrict to the "target" element which is clicked

Comment: It doesn't, but, `this` will be the one that was clicked, not all of them.

Comment: "this"  doesn't refer to clicked element or is equal to "target"

Comment: In this case it does. The only time it doesn't in a click event is when you use a bound function or the event is bound to a parent. In this case it is bound directly to the anchor tag, so `evt.target` and `this` are the same node.

Comment: just try console.log(this) vs console.log(evt.target)